# Make a transaction from a node not in network

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

I have a smart contract deployed on one node. This node has another node in the same network.

Is it possible to make a transaction from a 3rd node to the 1st, when both are not in the same network?

Comment: How should the blockchain nodes find the new transaction if the node used is not connected?

Answer (score 0):

What does "same network" mean? Every node is in a "virtual" same network, not the same LAN. They are connected through a p2p network, not a local router.

Comment: By same network, I meant that both are peers of each other and are getting synced completely. The 3rd node isn't a peer as I don't want my entire blockchain to be synced in it. It should work like a wallet.